# Calculating Interatomic Distances with Python for Large Scale Simulations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

In a project I need to build neighbor-list of atoms. For that, I have to calculate inter-atomic distances and get 10 closest atoms for each atom. Also I need to implement periodic boundary conditions in each dimension. For instance if the simulation box size is 20A an atom at 19A is 2.1A far from an atom at 0.1A. Also there are more than 1 000 000 atoms in the system.
My initial approach was:

```
   neighborlist=[None]*frame.natoms
   amap=[]
   XA=[]
   XB=[]
   length=frame.boxhi-frame.boxlo
   for i in range(frame.natoms):
       if frame.atoms[i].symbol !='Ti' : continue # exclude non ti atoms
       XA.append(frame.atoms[i].coord)
       amap.append(i)
   for j in range(frame.natoms):
       XB.append(frame.atoms[j].coord)
   XWrapped=XB
   cnt=0
   XA=np.asarray(XA,dtype=np.float32)
   for ix in range(-1,2,1):
       for iy in range(-1,2,1):
          for iz in range(-1,2,1):
              if ix==0 and iy==0 and iz==0 : continue
              cnt+=1
              vec=np.multiply([ix,iy,iz],length)
              Xp=np.add(XB,vec)
              XWrapped=np.concatenate((XWrapped,Xp),axis=0)
   start_dist=timer()
   distmatrix=distance.cdist(XA,XWrapped,metric='euclidean')
```

This code works fine and fast for up to 10 000 atoms. Above that it gives memory error.
Another idea is to split the XA, XWrapped vectors but I am not sure about the performance.
Is there a better/faster way to do this?
I have tried implementing PBC via if clauses but cdist was faster.

Comment: have a look at [Scipy's KD Tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)

Comment: I am not sure that you can implement PBC with KD Tree.

Comment: yes I see your point maybe if you had some kind of coordinate transformation into cylinderical space?

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand this part. Why transforming to cylindrical space would help here?

Comment: because then you could put the [2 boundaries of your box next to each other](https://i.imgur.com/jiBucTz.png)